# Django: Inheriting from a class that has djangofsm field and not able to call the transition

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a abstract django model

```
from django_fsm import FSMField, transition
from django.db.models import Model, NullBooleanField, TextField

class ApprovalMixin(Model):
    status = FSMField(default='new')
    is_approved = NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    """Meta Attributes"""
    abstract = True
```

Then I am inhering this class in another model:

```
class Request(ApprovalMixin):
    notes = TextField(blank=True, null=True, help_text="ts notes")

@transition(field=status, source='new',
            target='rejected')
def manager_rejection(self):
    pass
```

I am getting the following error:
**NameError: name 'status' is not defined** why is this? The `status` should be part of Request models right since I am inheriting from the `ApprovalMixin`. If I am wrong, Please help me out on how to make this work.

Comment: Could you fix the indentation (either in the question, or the code)

Comment: @ashwoods the indendation seems fine. Just copy pasting it in to a model file works

Answer (score 3):

From django-fsm docs:

```
 The field parameter accepts both
 a string attribute name or an actual
 field instance.
```